# Syntax for symbol literal

Tags: ruby, symbols, literals

Some code examples have `element:` for symbols and other times the syntax is `:element`.  I found a definition of a symbol [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_symbols.html), but I'm not sure what `:element` is.  My understanding is that a symbol is like a constant.  But what does the other syntax mean?

Comment: `{hello: 1, goodbye: 2} #=> {:hello=>1, :goodbye=>2}`

Comment: Referring to the symbol definition, how can you know what `element:` is without being sure what `:element` is? Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: _"Some code examples"_ – show them, please. How do the examples look likes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Symbol is defined in Ruby as an "internalized string", or in other words, a string singleton of sorts. They have some interesting properties, but most importantly they have very minimal memory impact.

Any given symbol, like `:example`, is the same object as every other instance of that symbol. This is not the case for strings where `"example"` and `"example"` might be identical in terms of content, yet in terms of objects are different. Ruby identifies objects by their internal `object_id`:

```
"example".object_id == "example".object_id
# => false
:example.object_id == :example.object_id
# => true
```

This makes them ideal for use in hashes as keys, for flags where memory efficiency and performance are concerns.

Comparing two symbols is very easy. They're either the same object or not. For strings a lot of additional work is required to evaluate if they're identical or not, each character needs to be compared, and as they can contain arbitrary UTF or binary data, this is not always simple.

The one thing to note is you should only use symbols where you'd otherwise type something in, that "symbolizing" arbitrary values is wasteful. For example, if your hash contains a UUID as a key, something that's unlikely to ever duplicate, store it as a string. Each symbol, generally speaking, stays in Ruby memory for the duration of the program, so you pay a small one-time cost for the symbol itself.

This cost can add up if you declare millions of them, though. If the symbol is only ever used once that could cause a lot of excess memory use, defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As Sagar pointed out, one of the use cases for symbols is using the symbol for the keys of a Hash.  It can be helpful for performance, imaging using 500 instances of a certain key and in reality all you need is one because it is identifying the key in the Hash.

it can also be used for method calls and to set getters/setters among other things.

Basically symbols are just a string that can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`a: 'b'` is a shortcut for `:a => 'b'`. That's all.